# Prove $X$ is compact iff for each family $\{ F_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$ with the FIP, we have $\cap F_\alpha\neq\varnothing$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, proof-verification

I'm reading Intro to Topology from Mendelson.

The entire problem statement is,

Prove that $X$ is compact if and only if for each family $\lbrace F_\alpha\rbrace_{\alpha\in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$ that has the finite intersection property, we have $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} F_\alpha\neq\varnothing$.

My attempt at the proof is as follows:

First assume that $X$ is compact. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that there exists a family $\{ F_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$ with FIP such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} F_\alpha=\varnothing$. Since $X$ is compact if $\lbrace F_\alpha\rbrace_{\alpha\in I}$ any family of closed sets such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} F_\alpha=\varnothing$, then there exists a finite set of indices $\lbrace \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\rbrace$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n F_{\alpha_i}=\varnothing$. Yet, since $\lbrace F_\alpha\rbrace_{\alpha\in I}$ has the finite intersection property, for every finite index of $J\subset I$, $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I} F_\alpha\neq\varnothing$.

Suppose now that $X$ is not compact, that is, there exists an open cover $\lbrace U_\alpha\rbrace_{\alpha\in I}$ of $X$ with no finite subcover. Consider the set $F_\alpha=C(U_\alpha).$ Then $\lbrace F_\alpha\rbrace_{\alpha\in I}$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property and were $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} F_\alpha=\varnothing.$

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: The first paragraph certainly needs to be rewritten more clearly. "Empty intersection over an index, like the one mentioned earlier" is particularly confusing.

Comment: You're right so I went ahead and made an edit. Hopefully it sounds more clear now.

Comment: There is no inherent contradiction in the first paragraph because you don't explicitly assume compactness.

Comment: I see, is better now?

Comment: I made a few edits, mostly minor. Note that `\{\}` does the same thing as `\lbrace\rbrace` with fewer characters, and that `\bigcap` is usually more readable with subscripts/superscripts than is `\cap`. The last sentence of the first paragraph is still completely unreadable.

Comment: In the converse, the negation of compactness is not "for every open cover of X, no finite subcover exists". The negation is "there exists an open cover of X such that no finite subcover exists".

Comment: You're right xyzzyz, I'll go ahead and make the adjustments and see what comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your proof goes well, but it needs more explanation. Here is an attempt.

Suppose that $X$ is compact and let $\{F_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ be a family of closed subsets of $X$ with $FIP$. On contrary, suppose that $\cap_{\alpha\in I}F_\alpha=\emptyset$. Then $\cup_{\alpha\in I}F_\alpha^c=X$. As $X$ is compact, so there is a finite subset $J$ of $I$ such that $\cup_{\alpha\in J}F_\alpha^c=X$ and consequently $\cap_{\alpha\in J}F_\alpha^c=\emptyset$, which is a contradiction to $FIP$.

Conversely, let $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ be an open cover of $X$. Now put $F_\alpha=U_\alpha^c$. If $X$ is not compact then the family $\{F_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$, of closed subsets of $X$, has $FIP$ with $\cap_{\alpha\in I}F_\alpha=\emptyset$, which contradicts our hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for the response and cleaning up the proof considerably.